# How to change color of all holidays in Outlook 2010?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

I added my national holidays by

`Outlook -> Options -> Calendar -> Calendar options -> Add holidays`

Now I want to change the color of all holidays at once. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select a holiday entry in Calendar.

Open the Color Categories dialog

Tab Home-> Categorize-> All Categories

[image]

Comment: Is there a chance to use different colors for holiday from different countries?

Comment: In the list view this can be done fast...